# Vimscript print function?

Tags: function, vim, viml

Is there a function in Vimscript or a convention that allows you to simply print text to the editor? The function `echo` only supplies a command line print function, and does not actually print to the editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say "print to the editor", I take it you mean "print to the current buffer".  If that's correct, take a look at `:help append()`.

Answer (score 2):

A facility I sometimes use is `:redir @"` (or `:redir @a` for register `a`), which redirects the output of commands to a buffer, so you can `p`aste it. To stop output redirection, say `:redir end`. See `:help :redir`.